# how to understand cls* (*) (int, double)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on some source codes grabbed from Internet and find a confused sentence.

```
map<int, Element* (*) (int, Domain*) > elemList
```

My question is for the value part of elemList. Is is a pointer ? Or constructor function? Or some else ?

Best regards

Comment: It's a function pointer. Look where the map is used.

Comment: If we follow [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) then `Element* (*) (int, Domain*)` is a pointer to a function (taking one `int` and one `Domain*` argument) that returns a pointer to `Element`. [Decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have mentioned function pointers.

Comment: @RetiredNinja

I would like to express my thanks for your attention and your answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:

Thanks for your nice and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`Element* (*) (int, Domain*)` is for function pointers. These are of two types.

- Raw function pointers (which is something like this: `void (*foo)(int x, int y);`).
- Member function pointers (which looks something like this: `void (Object::*foo)(int x, int y);`).

In a raw function pointer, its made of 3 parts. Lets use the above example,

1. Return type (which is `void`).
2. Function name/ pointer name (which is `foo`).
3. Function parameters (which is `(int x, int y)`).

In a member function pointer, its made of 4 parts.

1. Return type (which is `void`).
2. Which class/ struct holds the function (which is `Object`).
3. Function name/ pointer name (which is `foo`).
4. Function parameters (which is `(int x, int y)`).

Calling a raw function pointer is as easy as this,

```cpp
void Func(int x, int y) { ... }

void (*foo)(int x, int y) = Foo;    // Assigning the function pointer.
foo();    // Calling the pointer.
```

Calling a member function pointer is slightly different. For this you need a valid instance of the object.

```cpp
class Object {
public:
    void Func(int x, int y) { ... }
};


void (Object::*foo)(int x, int y) = &Object::Func;    // Assigning the function pointer. Notice the '&' operator here.

Object object;
(object.*foo)();    // Calling the function pointer.
```

So what `map<int, Element* (*) (int, Domain*) > elemList` does is, it stores a map of raw function pointers which is mapped to an integer.

Additional: In order to assign a function to a function pointer, these things should match,

- The return type.
- Parameters of the function.
- The object which holds the function (this is only for member functions).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer to my question